# Javascript class's function is undefined

Tags: javascript, class, undefined

I'm currently running into a problem using classes in Javascript. My problem:

I have an array of objects

```
...
objects: []
...
```

At a certain point, I insert a class

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.x = 0;
obj.y = 0;

objects.push(obj);
```

When I later iterate  through the array, I try to call the render function. But the console then tells me the function is undefined. If I check my console and log the the object, there are no functions present anymore. But if I log the class itself it can find the function.

```
Object in console returns the entire body of the class

Object.Render(); returns undefined in the console, but I see it when I just log 'Object'.
```

My class looks something like this:

```
function Object() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;

    this.Render = function() {
         ...
    }
}
```

Loggin an element from the array just displayes the classes' variables, no functions.

Am I doing something wrong, or should I use a different approach? I just want an array filled with objects of this class, so I'm avoiding

```
var Object = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,

    render: function(){
       ...
    }
}
```

since I can't new these (because its an object).

Any help is appreciated!

Kind regards,

Nick

Comment: You might want to make sure that the `this` inside of your constructor function is the `this` you are expecting. You could very easily be assigning your `x` and `y` properties (and your `Render` function) to another object without realizing it. You wouldn't notice this because you set `x` and `y` after you create your object.

Comment: Please, change function name `Object` to something else

Comment: And just before I edited my comment to mention it... is your function actually called `Object`? That's already a type in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure, but `Object` is built-in class and I think you can't redeclare its constructor. So use `MyObject` or something else for your constructor.

Comment: It isn't called object, and I found the problem. I was added objects to this array that I was retrieving from a database, and checked by ID if they were already present in the array. I forgot that, in a test file, I just added the object from the database (not the class, so no functions there). Once the loader arrived at the place where it actually adds it as a class it detected that there was already an object in the array with the same ID. STUPID ME! Guess I should get some more coffee.

Thanks for the quick replies guys!

Comment: You should self-answer your question rather than editing your question with a 'solved!' message :-)

Comment: Site policy is not to update questions to say "solved" or similar. If your resolution was a programming one, you could write your own answer and accept it at an appropriate point. As it is, it is basically a "typo" and likely to be closed as such.

Answer (score 0):

The render function is defined on this and not on the function Object. So if you do var obj = new Object(). obj.Render() would work and not Object.Render()

Comment: This is incorrect. The OP is calling `new` on his constructor, so anything that is assigned to `this` inside of the constructor is assigned to the resulting object. Of course, this only holds true if the function is not bound to another this context. OP **should** define the method on the prototype - `Constructor.prototype.render = function() {}` - to avoid this.